# jQuery animate callback is not triggered after queue:false has been used?

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

Why the animate **callback** is not triggered after `queue:false` has been used?

For instance, a callback occurs here.

```
$("#move").click(function(){

        $(".box").animate({ 
            marginLeft: "100px"
        },500 , function() {

            alert('complete');
            console.log('complete');
        });

        return false;
});
```

but not with this,

```
$("#move").click(function(){

        $(".box").animate({ 
            marginLeft: "100px"
        }, { queue:false, duration:500 } , function() {

            alert('complete');
            console.log('complete');
        });

        return false;
});
```

the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PGn9X/) to jsfiddle

Can I have both `queue:false` and `callback` at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is wrong:

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PGn9X/1/)

The jquery animate [is defined as follows](http://api.jquery.com/animate/): `.animate( properties, options )`

```
$("#move").click(function(){

        $(".box").animate({ 
            marginLeft: "100px",
         queue:false, duration:500 } , 5000, function() {

            alert('complete');
            console.log('complete');
        });

        return false;
});
```

Comment: can I ask - what the difference between the 500 in duration and the 5000?

Comment: it is just the duration in milliseconds. By default in jquery animate, the duration is set to 400

Answer (score 6):

That will not work karthikr... the queue will not function anymore.
as you mentioned animate is defined as .animate( properties, options ).You need to make the callback a part of the options argument:

```
$("#move").click(function(){

    $(".box").animate({ 
        marginLeft: "100px",
     },{queue:false, duration:500, complete:function() {

          alert('complete');
          console.log('complete');
        }//callback function
    });//options and animate

    return false;
});
```